# Locate asymmetries in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have generated matrix of pairwise distances between list items, but something went wrong and it is not symmetric.

In the case the matrix looks like this:

```
array = np.array([
    [0, 3, 4],
    [3, 0, 2],
    [1, 2, 0]
])
```

How can I locate the actual asymmetries? In this case, the indices of 4 and 1.

I have confirmed the asymmetry by trying to condense the matrix by scipy squareform function, and then using

```py
def check_symmetric(a, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08):
    return np.allclose(a, a.T, rtol=rtol, atol=atol)
```

Comment: what does locate the acutal asymmetrie means? could you give a low dimensional example?

Comment: Sorry, I have added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite late but here would be a alternative the numpy way...

```py
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[0, 3, 4 ],
             [ 3, 0, 2 ],
             [ 1, 2, 0 ]])

def check_symmetric(a):

    diff = a - a.T

    boolmatrix = np.isclose(a, a.T) # play around with your tolerances here...

    output = np.argwhere(boolmatrix == False)

    return output
```

output:

```py
check_symmetric(m)

>>> array([[0, 2],
           [2, 0]])
```

Comment: Your function is not using its local variables but the global ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the negation of `np.isclose()`:

```
mask = ~np.isclose(array, array.T)
mask
# array([[False, False,  True],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [ True, False, False]])
```

Use that value as an index to get the values:

```
array[mask]
# array([4, 1])
```

And use `np.where()` if you want the indices instead:

```
np.where(mask)
# (array([0, 2]), array([2, 0]))
```

Answer (score -2):

The following is quick and slow but if the object is to debug will probably do.

```
a  #  nearly symmetric array.
Out:
array([[8, 1, 6, 5, 3],
       [1, 9, 4, 4, 4],
       [6, 4, 3, 7, 1],
       [5, 4, 7, 5, 2],
       [3, 4, 1, 3, 7]])
```

Define function to find and print the differences.

```
ERROR_LIMIT = 0.00001
def find_asymmetries( a ):
    """ Prints the row and column indices with the difference 
        where abs(a[r,c] - a[c,r]) > ERROR_LIMIT """
    res = a-a.T
    for r, row in enumerate(res):
        for c, cell in enumerate(row):
            if abs(cell) > ERROR_LIMIT : print( r, c, cell )

find_asymmetries( a )
3 4 -1
4 3 1
```

This version halves the volume of results.

```
def find_asymmetries( a ):
    res = a-a.T
    for r, row in enumerate(res):
        for c, cell in enumerate(row):
            if c == r: break #   Stop column search once c == r
            if abs(cell) > ERROR_LIMIT : print( r, c, cell )

find_asymmetries( a )
4 3 1   # Row number always greater than column number
```

Comment: Your function does not return any values, but prints them instead. And there is no need for `for` loops here.